# Images not loading when trying with domain name instead of IP address

Tags: php, digital-ocean, opencart2.x

I have hosted one of my website at DigitalOcean. The problem I am facing is, whenever I am trying to load my website by typing IP address at browser, it is loading fine. But on the other side, if I am loading it using my domain name, the images are not loading properly.

Below details may help you to track the actual problem:

IP Address: 128.199.208.187
Domain Name: ceekraft.com

FYI - the site is an opencart theme. And the images are loading fine in Safari, for both the cases.

Comment: did you check the URL for the images in both cases to verify that they are the same ?

Comment: also have you tried to clear the image cache ?

Comment: Use relative paths for local images. Then your site will be portable to any ip or domain name `src="image/cache/catalog/demo/shoe_2/6c-450x463.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

I've tested with Chrome Console

The problem is that you've put IP address somewhere in your code, and browser will interpret this as cross-domain origin...

```
Font from origin 'http://128.199.208.187' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ceekraft.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: So what should be the solution? How Safari is able to load the images properly?

Comment: update the hard coded `http://128.199.208.187` in your HTML or/and PHP scripts. use relative path : `src="/ceekraft/image/cache/catalog/demo/shoe_2/6c-450x463.jpg"` instead of `src="http://128.199.208.187/ceekraft/image/cache/catalog/demo/shoe_2/6c-450x463.jpg"`. You can enable cross-domain in all web browsers but it's not the default configuration, since it's considered as a security issue, except for Safari i think...

Answer (score 0):

When you go on inspect element, your image is pointing on your IP.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://128.199.208.187/ceekraft/image/cache/catalog/demo/shoe_2/6c-450x463.jpg" alt="Nunc eismods">
```

Try to reupload one image directly on your domain in open cart to see if it's going to work ok.

Answer (score 0):

ServerAlias [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) http://example.com/ http://www.example.com/ example.com

Replace above alias name with below alias name

ServerAlias [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Comment: Please explain how this is meant to be implemented, how it works and how you meant it to solve the problem. Partially it seems to be a no-operation and I simply do not see a realtion to the question.